# Slow printf: why does __USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO=0 make it faster?

Tags: c, performance, printf

I wrote the code for a problem in codeforces and even though I believe I was doing it in the best time complexity it was exceeding the time limit on the 7th test case. After some testing, it seemed to me that the major amount of time was being taken by printf, which seemed odd since using printf some 3 * 10^5 times shouldn't be such a big deal. So I searched a lot and found this: https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/105687#comment-940911
Now I made the conclusion that using this line at the top of my code will make printf faster:

```
#define __USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO 0
```

So I ran my code with the above included and voila what was exceeding the time limit of 1s earlier now with the inclusion of just one line of code got accepted in merely 62 ms.
I didn't understand most of the other stuff that was talked about in the link like MinGW implementations and all.
So my question is, firstly why does it work this way? Secondly, can I/should I keep using the above line of code in all my programs on codeforces from now on?

P.S. I also found this blog: https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/47180
It was too confusing for me to grasp for the time being but maybe someone else can understand it and shed some light on the matter.

Also, here is the codeforces problem: https://codeforces.com/contest/1774/problem/C
Here is my solution:
https://codeforces.com/contest/1774/submission/185781891

I don't know the entire input as codeforces doesn't share it and it'd be very very big. But I know that the value inputted to the tests variable is 3, the values inputted to n[0], n[1], n[2] are 100000, 100000, 100000

Here is my code:

```
#define __USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO 0
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
// #include <math.h>
// #include <string.h>

// #define lint long long int

// Function Declarations

int main(void)
{
    int tests;
    scanf("%i", &tests);
    int **answers = malloc(tests * sizeof(int*));
    int *n = malloc(sizeof(int) * tests);
    for (int i = 0; i < tests; i++)
    {
        scanf("%i", &n[i]);
        char *enviro = malloc((n[i]) * sizeof(int));
        answers[i] = malloc((n[i] - 1) * sizeof(int));
        int consec = 1; // No. of same consecutive elements at the very 
                        // end.
        scanf("%s", enviro);
        answers[i][0] = 1; // Case where x = 2;
        for (int x = 3; x < n[i] + 1; x++)
        {
            // comparing corresponding to current x vs previous x
            if (enviro[x - 2] == enviro[x - 3])
            {
                consec++;
            }
            else
            {
                 consec = 1;
            }
            answers[i][x - 2] = x - consec;
        }
        // Free loop variables
        free(enviro);
    }
    /* if (tests == 3)
    {
        printf("n[%i] = %i\n", i, n[i]);
    } */
    for (int i = 0; i < tests; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n[i] - 1; j++)
        {
            printf("%i ", answers[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        free(answers[i]);
    }
    // Free variables
    free(answers);
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: So I tried the following code for the same problem on codeforces (https://codeforces.com/contest/1774/submission/185788962) just to see the execution time:

```
// #define __USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO 0
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n = pow(10, 5);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("*");
    }
}
```

Without the #define __USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO 0 it gave an e.t. of 374ms. With it, it gave e.t. of 15ms.

Comment: "Can I use such code on X site" is, in my opinion, an uninteresting question. Maybe you wanted to ask "What makes such code better" or "How does such code work"?

Comment: @anatolyg Sure, nothing better if you can help me understand what's going on. But I was also worried as to whether this would be allowed on codeforces or not, as I don't want to get banned because of this, hence the phrasing I used in the question. I edited the question as per your recommendation.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know the answer, but I am sure someone else here does. To make your question clearer, maybe you can post the input to your code? Regarding "whether it's allowed", I think there is absolutely no problem, but this site is the wrong place to ask. It's a programming site — much greater probability that people know how it works than whether it's allowed.

Comment: What input was used, especially for `scanf("%s", enviro);`?   Please explain line of code: `char *enviro = malloc((n[i]) * sizeof(int));`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica umm.. a string of 0s and 1s is the input to enviro, of length n - 1. Hence I have used a character array of size n to store it. I don't know the exact string but it'd look like: 1000101001110110.....

Comment: @RubyShanks Please provide an exact sample of input you used that caused the issue.  I suspect you are overrunning `enviro[]`.

Comment: Can you remove `scanf` and instead hardcode the values inside the program `tests = something; n[0] = something; n[1] = osmething; etc.`, does including `__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO` also make a difference?

Comment: I suspect the details of what exactly the code calculates are unimportant. I guess you can reproduce this by a bunch of random `printf("%i ", n)`.

Comment: @KamilCuk Please see my edit at the bottom of the question. Does that help?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems like MinGW defined their own `printf()` functions, `__mingw_printf()`. This is done to fix format specifiers' problems on some old Windows operating systems, as seen in their [wikis](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/wiki2/gnu%20printf/). The macro `__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO` is set to 0 if you don't want to use MinGW's implementation, and 1 if you do.

It also seems like MinGW's implementation is slower, so not using it will make your code faster.

Comment: It’s not even necessarily old Windows systems that benefit from the MinGW implementation of printf. In fact, my version of MinGW on Windows 10 complains when I use the %zu format specifier unless this macro is set.